# XML-serialization with derived types

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, derived-class

I´ve again a problem on getting my serializer to work. I have a baseclass A and a derived class B:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A foo = new B();

        // determine that the class B overrides A
        XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        overrides.Add(typeof(A), new XmlAttributes
        {
            XmlElements = { new XmlElementAttribute("B", typeof(B)) }
        });

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A), overrides);
        ser.Serialize(new XmlTextWriter("test.xml", Encoding.Default), foo);

    }
}

public class A { public int a;}
public class B : A { public int b;}
```

But when I run this little program I get exception

> XmlRoot and XmlType attributes may not be specified for the type ConsoleApplication1.A

but I never determined the root or type-attribute for class A so I´m really confused about this message. Is there anything behind the scenes I have to specify? All I want do is serialize an instance of B that simply add some properties to the definition of A...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got two solutions to work:

Number 1:

```
...
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A));
ser.Serialize(new XmlTextWriter("test.xml", Encoding.Default), foo);
...         

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Root", Namespace = "DefaultNS")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(B))]
public class A { public int a;}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(Namespace = "CustomNS")]
public class B : A { public int b;}
```

Number 2 (in addition to Ondrejs solution):

```
...
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A), overrides, new[] { typeof(B) }, new XmlRootAttribute("Root"), "defautlNS");
...

public class A { public int a;}
public class B : A { public int b;}
```

The second one in contrast to the first solution has the disadvantage that you may not see where an attribute within the XML-document comes from (from defaultNS or customNS) since you cannot specify any customNS.

Comment: I added the third parameter to the XmlSerializer to specify an array of possible types which may derive from A also (in addition to B).

Answer (score 4):

It is right there in the error message you are getting.

> XmlRoot and XmlType attributes may not be specified for the type ConsoleApplication1.A

You have to specify a root element for the output xml document.

Replace

```
overrides.Add(typeof(A), new XmlAttributes
```

with

```
overrides.Add(typeof(A), "node", new XmlAttributes
```

And you will have to probably also replace

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(A), overrides);
```

with

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(B), overrides);
```

For more info and example on overriding, please visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I have also added a solution for another error that occured after the first one has been fixed. Please, look at the example on MSDN, I posted a link in my answer as well.

Comment: I suppose the definiton of the serilaizer with `typeof(B)` won´t let us serialize further implementations of A, will it? With an array of types as third parameter for the constructor it may work, see may answer.

Comment: Nope. But your question sound differently. "All I want do is serialize an instance of B that simply add some properties to the definition of A." You had not said nothing about serializing another derived classes.

Comment: There's a very good chance that the error message itself is erroneous. And has not been fixed for over 7 years.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/726317a0-aaff-468c-b099-f47227190bf3/misleading-error-message-from-xmlserializer-constructor?forum=asmxandxml